# Run a single Gradle task without dependency tasks

Tags: gradle, gradle-multi-project-build

What are ways to minimize Gradle runtime when running a single task that is known to have no task dependencies on a project containing many sub-projects (over 100) where just configuration phase takes over 80 seconds? Most time is wasted in configuration phase, configuring tasks that are known not to be executed.

I'm aware of [`--exclude-task`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_executing_tasks) that allows to exclude a task from running. However this seems a bit clumsy since I'd like to exclude all but one task.

There is also a [Configuration cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/configuration_cache.html) however it is still an incubation effort (as of version 7.4.2) and it conflicts with some used features like `Gradle.addBuildListener`.

Comment: 80 seconds taken in the configuration phase?  maybe it's time for a refactoring in your script in order to implement https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html   , i don't think you will find any way to "skip" some of the configuration phase

Comment: you could also give a try to incubating feature https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/configuration_cache.html